# How to hide the tabcomponent

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

Am using the Ionic2 Conference App as a base. how to hide the below highlighted tab in the application, the left navigation is enough for my application

Please advise

[image: fdsfs]

Comment: see ng-hide or ng-if .

Comment: Why is this being upvoted? So hilarious. If i spend half an hour writing a question about XSS I get downvoted for not checking docs. This is the most basic application of Ionic2

Comment: Wouldn't it simply remove the tab component?